# Software for numerical solution to simultaneous nonlinear algebraic equations with trancendental terms

Tags: numerical-analysis

I'm having trouble with convergence while using EES (Engineering Equations Solver).  I have a system of five simultaneous nonlinear algebraic equations in which the unknown quantities often appear as arguments of Sine and Cosine functions. I believe EES uses a Newton Raphson technique and it is thus sensitive to initial guesses.  Can anyone recommend freely available software that might be better suited for such problems?  Thanks in advance.